# Content type with template

Tags: office-365, content-type, publishing

I have set up a content type syndication hub and created a new content type (Document Set) with the default content based on .xlsx file.

There is no any template created on `https://..tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/contentTypeHub`

The content type has been successfully published and I see it on subscribers sites.

My question:
Is it possible to publish a content type with a template?

**Update**:

It works as it is intended to work. I am not proud of my question. Still learning Sharepoint ... (confused templates with the default content of content type)

Comment: your new content type should inherits your template content type

Comment: But it doesn't for a published content type. The template (the default content based on xlsx file) has not been even created on https://..tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/contentTypeHub. I do not mean the content type itself, it works.